# byte array to double conversion in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array of three bytes, I want to convert array into double using c#. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Providing your code would be a good start to getting an answer

Comment: What endian notation are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well a double is an array of 8 bytes, so with 3 bytes you won't have all the possible values.

To do what you want:

```
var myBytes[] = {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2}; //assume you pad your array with enough zeros to make it 8 bytes.
var myDouble = BitConverter.ToDouble(myBytes,0);
```

Comment: I have tried this approach, but it cause the exception. I don't know why.

Comment: Is your data in the correct floating point format (i believe that C# uses the standard IEEE Floating Point format)

Answer (score 5):

Well, that depends on what you want the conversion to do.

You can convert *8* bytes (in the right format) into a `double` using `BitConverter.ToDouble` - but with only *three* bytes it's a bit odd - after all, a `double` has 64 bits of information, normally. How do those three bytes represent a number? What's the format, basically? When you've figured that out, the rest may well be easy.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what exactly is stored in the bytes, but you might be able to just pad the array with 5 bytes all containing 0 and then use [BitConverter.ToDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbcydc7a.aspx).